# Avant que plus subjonctif (présent/passé)

Tags: temps-grammatical, conjonctions, subjonctif

> Je pars avant qu'il arrive.
>
> Je pars avant qu'il soit arrivé.

Je ne comprends pas totalement le sens de la seconde phrase que j'ai vue dans un livre et la différence avec la première.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux phrases ont le même sens. Il y a cependant une très légère différence: Dans la première "arrive" peut exprimer plusieurs choses. On peut dire "j'arrive" pour dire qu'on est actuellement en train d'arriver mais qu'on est pas encore arrivé. La première phrase pourrait donc vouloir dire "Je pars avant qu'il se mette en route pour arriver ici". La deuxième phrase ne laisse aucun doute, "Je pars avant qu'il ne soit ici". Même si dans les faits ici les deux phrases ont globalement le même sens et seront toutes deux comprises par un natif.